# Two Photon Absorption dependence on Semiconductor Band Gap

Tags: visible-light, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, absorption

It's well known that Two Photon Absorption coefficient is scaling with $E_g^{-3}$. Does anyone know what is the physical reason for this scaling? What is the physical theory behind this mathematics?

Comment: Where did you find this formula? There should be references there that you could consult. Please update your question with the results of this research.